# Accessing airflow operator value outside of operator

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

Outside of an operator, I need to call a SubdagOperator and pass it an operator's return value, using xcom. I've seen tons of solutions ([Airflow - How to pass xcom variable into Python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46059161/airflow-how-to-pass-xcom-variable-into-python-function), [How to retrieve a value from Airflow XCom pushed via SSHExecuteOperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974051/how-to-retrieve-a-value-from-airflow-xcom-pushed-via-sshexecuteoperator), etc).

They all basically say 'variable_name': "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='some_task_id') }}"

But my Jinja template keeps getting rendered as a string, and not returning the actual variable. Any ideas why?

Here is my current code in the main dag:

```
PARENT_DAG_NAME = 'my_main_dag'
CHILD_DAG_NAME = 'run_featurization_dag'

run_featurization_task = SubDagOperator(
    task_id=CHILD_DAG_NAME,
    subdag=run_featurization_sub_dag(PARENT_DAG_NAME, CHILD_DAG_NAME, default_args, cur_date, "'{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_num_accounts', dag_id='" + PARENT_DAG_NAME + "') }}'" ),  
    default_args=default_args,
    dag=main_dag
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Too many quotes? Try this one

```
"{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_num_accounts', dag_id='" + PARENT_DAG_NAME + "') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Jinja templating works only for certain parameters, not all.

```
You can use Jinja templating with every parameter that is marked as “templated” in the documentation. Template substitution occurs just before the pre_execute function of your operator is called.
```

https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#jinja-templating

So I'm afraid you can't pass a variable this way.